# How to automatically generate a page after user fills a form via PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms, directory

Let's say I have a form with two input fields, title and comment. After the user fills the two fields and submits the data, a page is automatically created that contains the title and comment that the user typed, in a folder located in root directory, for example, www.root.com/page/ will contain the automatically generated page.

Update:

I'd like the form data to be sent to an SQL table row with the url of the auto-generated page to be in the same SQL row as the title and comment.

How do I do this via PHP?

Comment: you could do it that way, but typically you'd store the values in a database and then fetch them when the page is loaded. unless you have a practical reason for wanting to write out files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php
//Template for basic page
$template = <<<EOD
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><!--TITLE--></title>
</head>

<body>
<!--COMMENT-->
</body>
</html>
EOD;

//handle the posted form
if(isset($_POST['title'])&&isset($_POST['comment'])){
    //replace the areas of the template with the posted values
    $page = str_replace('<!--TITLE-->',htmlentities($_POST['title']),$template);
    $page = str_replace('<!--COMMENT-->',htmlentities($_POST['comment']),$page);
    //create a name for the new page
    $pagename = md5($_POST['title']).'.html';

    //db connect & select
    $db=mysql_connect('localhost','user','pass');
    mysql_select_db('yourdb');

    //check if page already exists
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT pagename from yourtable WHERE url="'.mysql_real_escape_string($pagename).'"');
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>=1){
        $notice = '<p>Page already created <b>./pages/'.$pagename.'</b></p>';
    }else{
        //inset new page into db
        mysql_query('INSERT into yourtable (`id`,`title`,`comment`,`url`)VALUES("",
        "'.mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['title'])).'",
        "'.mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['comment'])).'",
        "'.$pagename.'")');
        //put the created content to file
        file_put_contents('./pages/'.$pagename,$page);
        //make a notice to show the user
        $notice = '<p>New Page created <b>./pages/'.$pagename.'</b></p>';
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-gb">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Make page example</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
//if the notice is set then display it
if(isset($notice)){echo $notice;} ?>
<form method="POST" action="">
  <p>Title:<input type="text" name="title" size="31"></p>
  <p>Comment:</p>
  <p><textarea rows="5" name="comment" cols="21"></textarea></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd like the form data to be sent to an SQL table row with the url of the auto-generated page to be in the same SQL row as the title and comment.

Comment: where does it say that in your question?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just remembered to put that in!

Comment: 4 columns: "id", "title", "comment", and "url".

Comment: amended, you get the idea. ill leave rest to you