# html/php page produced from form

Tags: php, sql

I have a form that submits data to sql, i am trying to create button that will push form data into a text of separate html/php page.
I don't know where to start, need vocabulary, tutorials.

Comment: Well, from what i get, you already have the form that post the data, what you need is to retrieve it from another page. To achieve that you are going to need to produce a select statement on that table and then show the data in your other page. There is plenty of tutorial online for that.

Comment: Here is the text: Welcome []! How do i insert selected value from sql table between the brackets in a text.

Comment: is unclear, and shouldn't need separate page(s), but a dupe of [How to automatically generate a page after user fills a form via PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261163/how-to-automatically-generate-a-page-after-user-fills-a-form-via-php/6261318#6261318)

Comment: Wonderful. The only thing is that i am a bit new to php scripting.

Comment: wahted to see if there is a piece of code with explanations/notation